Is there a historical concept where overland supply was impossible due to a distance and terrain that would lead suppliers to consume the supplies?
Is there a historical concept or even some occurrences, particularly in the era of preindustrial transportation, where overland war supply was impossible between two points due to the distance and intervening terrain that would lead suppliers to consume even the highest amount of supplies they could transport?
I'm more interested in theoretical cases that may or may not have had practical trials conducted by the supplied party or by earlier individuals they were aware of. Like if a historian said that king X couldn't use city Y for supplying the siege/garrison/etc... of Z for the reason I consider. Or even more abstract concepts like the impossibility of a certain land to be conquered due to this reason.

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s). At a minimum, all questions should explain why Wikipedia is insufficient.

I'm not sure that I understand the question well enough but this is dealt with in ACOUP:Supply, and in the various campaigns of the Tang against the Mongols.  The Manchu court made this argument against attacking the Oirat (they were wrong) Probably also on the Crusades in Egypt (that's from dim memory). Assuming that I understand the question.

I believe this is generally called logistical.constraints? One example might be Cambyses last campaign. AFAIK John Haldon's Warfare, State and Society has a calculation of how far a Byzantine army could march, assuming that creating supply depots or looting supplies in enemy territory would be unpractical.

Prior to the 16th century, the Spanish Kingdom did not fight the Aztec. Was it because they could not cross the Atlantic? Yes, obviously. But also because they had no idea there was anything to fight over. – And that is what an answer will go like for every case: You might be able to prove there were insurmountable transport difficulties, but not that they were a deciding factor for...something not to happen.

There was also a (relatively) small bit in The Baroque Cycle (well-researched historical fiction) that illustrated this happening in early modern France.

I'm more interested in theoretical cases that may or may not have had practical trials conducted by the supplied party or by earlier individuals they were aware of.

@FreezingSoul , move the comment into the question

@FreezingSoul "Theoretical cases" means "not history" and therefore off-topic. Are you asking for a list of every case where a hypothetical supply point was too far to be practical? The list could be virtually infinite.

@BrianZ Theoretical cases stated by historians as their opinion or facts.

Then there is Grant and Sherman intentionally disconnecting themselves from reliance on supply lines, with devastating results for the CSA.

As this is a hypothetical, it might be a better question for WorldBuilding.SE.

"tyranny of distance" or "logistical limit," and it occurs post industrialization too.  Occurred in Ukraine Russia hit their logistical limit a few hundred miles removed from their rail roads.  They didn't have enough fuel and trucks to continue their offensive so their troups sat on highways strung out over 60 kms.  Ukraine: Why has Russia's 64km convoy near Kyiv stopped moving?

https://acoup.blog/2022/07/29/collections-logistics-how-did-they-do-it-part-ii-foraging/ this.

@Luiz
"That in turn brought us to the ‘tyranny of the wagon equation’ – without modern industrial transport (initially railroads), a pre-industrial army cannot meet these supply needs the way a modern army might, through supply lines reaching back to operational bases in the rear and from there to the productive heartland of the army itself. Instead, because everything available that can readily move food also eats food, armies are forced to gather food and other supplies locally."
Wow that was exactly what I was on about, thanks.

@MCW Actually the mentioned user gave the link first but I didn't notice and just read the text in the comment itself, thanks MCW and Luiz.

The Wagon Equation
It's called the Tyranny of the Wagon Equation and you can read all about it here.  It means that an army is essentially incapable of operating farther than a few hundred miles (at best) from its base of operations unless it can move supplies by water OR it can get a huge amount of food by foraging.  Naturally not everywhere has rivers/coastline and a large army (or one moving at the wrong time through the wrong place, or one operating somewhere the natives are willing to burn their own crops) cannot rely on local food sources.
The wagon equation held from the invention of wagons up until railways took over.  When rail lines ran out/were insufficient the wagon equation took over again since in WWI all armies still used horse/oxen drawn wagons almost exclusively for supply. Prit Buttar notes several times throughout his excellent series on the Eastern Front in WWI that armies could not operate more than about 90-120 miles from their railheads because of logistical issues. If they tried to push beyond that their enemy invariably halted them/pushed them back. Granted WWI formations were way larger than anything preindustrial societies routinely put in the field, but the example has the benefit of very detailed records.
